# How to read a single .csv file that consists of multiple commented data frames of different lengths as a list?

Tags: r, csv, read.table, read.csv

I try to read a csv file with the following structure:

[image: my example]

Is it possible to read and save it as a single list where each entry is called Table A -- Monthly, Table B -- Monthly, Table C -- Monthly and so on? Also each list entry needs to be a data frame with the header "col1,col2,col3".

I know how to skip the text in the beginning, but how do I get rid of the "Copyright" in the end?

I'd really appreciate any suggestion to solve my problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume:

- the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end
- the table name lines are the only lines with --
- the table content and header lines are the only lines with a comma
- we can delete the leading , in any line starting with ,

Read the lines into `L` (in reality replace the argument with the filename) and extract the table name, heading and content lines and remove any leading comma giving `goodLines`.  Identify the positions of the table names `iNames` in that and then get the `Names` themselves.  Then split the goodLines, except for the table names, into a list of character vectors `s` and read each in setting the component names appropriately.

```
# L <- readLines("myfile.dat")
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
goodLines <- sub("^,", "", grep("--|,", L, value = TRUE)) 
iNames <- grepl("--", goodLines)
Names <- sub(" --.*", "", goodLines[iNames])
s <- split(goodLines[!iNames], cumsum(iNames)[!iNames])
setNames(lapply(s, function(x) read.csv(text = x)), Names)
```

giving the following list of data frames:

```
$`Table A`
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6

$`Table B`
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
junk
junk

Table A -- Monthly
,a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

Table B -- Monthly
,a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

junk
junk"
```